# jquery fetch value from a url using class

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am newbie in jquery/ajax i need some help in fetching some data from different webpage, Suppose i want to fetch data from a specific web page using jquery/ajax, I just want to copy a data from the class assigned on that page for example:

```
    <div class="stats">
<dl class="statscount">
<dt>total:</dt>
<dd>5,299</dd>
</dl>    
20000
    </div>
```

the class exists on all pages that i want to copy data,So i want to get the digits from pages within the class and save it in variables then add them. thats it. All the pages are on different domains but have same class. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Ajax to get data from other domain it will run up against [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).
That means that you can't get content from www.site1.com to www.site2.com. If you want to use ajax on the same domain. You can use the following code:

```
$('#result').load("http://www.yoursite.com .stats");
```

The way to do it properly is to use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

You can get data and div content from any site. Here is a sample code:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.yoursite.com/');
$stats = $html->find('.stats');
echo $stats->innertext;
```

Hope that helps.